# IntelliJ "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am on Intellij 2016.2.4

I have imported a project from Git (I am new to that).  I do now want to run a Module. I added to this Module every other Module Dependency and JAR Files needed. Their Scope is Compile. 
The project is running for others without changes.

If I make the Module I get:

```
java: cannot find symbol ; location: class utils.MyRandom
```

The method which cannot be found is in the other Module. Interestingly, if I click on the Classname and go to the definition, Intelij does decompile an `.class` file for that Class, and that file is missing two methods - those which cannot be found.

Furthermore an other Module needs that Class. But not the same Methods! If I make this Module it succeeds, but if I add for testing purposes the Methods, which are not available in the other Module, they do not work here too.

I have seen that there are already some Questions about that here, but there Answers doesn't help me.

[image]

The "wrong" Class is in COMMON. While any is not working here, other Methods from that Class are working in CLIENT.

Comment: Importing from Git shouldn't matter. How are you building the project? Is it Maven? Can't tell you anything without seeing the project and/or the project structure.

Comment: added a Picture, don´t knew what Structure I should show else

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide? I tested it with: I created in COMMON a new Class and in CLIENT I use this class. What´s happening? It is working without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the dependency for the module where you are calling the method, MyRandom is not properly defined,which is usually a issue when git repo is cloned, when some IDE specific dependencies are ignored while pushing.

Comment: I added an Pic. What dependency is there not correctly defined? Can´t see what I did wrong.

Comment: The method getAny() in RandomUtils class doesn't seem to be available from the class that it is dependent with.

Answer (score -2):

This might be conflict due to cache.
Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
This should work.

Thanks